# JSON object with place holders

Tags: java, json

I have a use case where I have to create a JSON object with place holders in my java application. The following JSON object has attribute1 and attribute3 required to resolved in my other microservice that has a register of these placeholders.

```
{ 
  "Attribute1": "myPlaceholder1"
  "Attribute2": "Value of Attribute 2"
  "Attribute3": "myPlaceholder2"...
}
```

I have a registry with the corresponding placeholder values to replace.

| Place holder id | Place holder value |
| --- | --- |
| myPlaceholder1 | U1 |
| myPlaceholder2 | U2 |

Is there a java/JSON library that allows me to define placeholders and allow me to replace these values at runtime?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you could organize your data in POJO or Record objects and use [jackson](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core) for runtime parsing. Jackson supports both parsing directions: Object <-> JSON

Comment: I could do that if the JSON structure was known at all times. I am storing the JSON in a CLOB field in a different table and the payload structure that I receive every time would be different from each sender. These senders would let me know which placeholder value is to be used for some of their attributes.

Comment: My service doesn't deem it necessary to know the POJO the JSON object would be mapped to. It is a medium to allow the payloads to be stored and passed on to a different service by manipulating certain values. 

For example the sender has the value A for place holder 1 and the corresponding value for the receiver is B for the same place holder 1

Comment: @AbdullahChougle Why not use Map<String, String> as a POJO? You can see my anwer below.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for your problem:

```java
try {
    String input = "{\"attr1\":\"value1\", \"attr2\":\"value2\"}";
    Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
    // this mapper is an instance of ObjectMapper from Spring (jackson library)
    data = mapper.readValue(input, data.getClass());
    System.out.println(data.toString());
    // here you can manipulate data and serialize it to string again if needed
} catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Take a note that the **readValue** has a warning but you can ignore it by **SuppressWarning("unchecked")**.